# Util-Linux Login not working with shadow password

Tags: linux, authentication

I downloaded `util-linux-2.12b` package and and built it. I need to use the `login` utility in the `login-utils` folder.

But after running it, it gives a "Login incorrect" for every user even with correct username/password.

---

Now it seems the utility is not working with /etc/shadow passowrds.

if I disable the shadow passwords by

```
#pwunconv
```

Its is working fine, while after enabling it with

```
#pwconv
```

It stops working again. :(

Comment: Recommending move to server-fault.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a build issue. Make sure you got your `configure` settings right. When I did alot of this building distros, it tended to be either a PAM/Unix authentication compile-time options not being set right or some prior package being bad.

**Good Luck!**

Comment: I guess so too.. I have updated the symptom with a new pointer.. pls take a look.

Comment: Also any links for resources for configuration option details... ./configure --help isnt working :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question, huh?

You can probably find more/better support by emailing the developer or posting on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).